# Index out of range in C# getting data from a datagridview

Tags: c#

I am trying to get data out of 2 cells on the last line of DataGridView in C#.  These lines of code give me Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```
intNumberOfRows = dgvWellsFargo.RowCount;

txtNoOfTransactions.Text = dgvWellsFargo.Rows[intNumberOfRows].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
txtTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c2}", dgvWellsFargo.Rows[intNumberOfRows].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

As you can see I am trying to use the RowCount for my index which I assume is what I need to use.  Is there another parameter that I should be using?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Collections start with index 0.  Be aware also that the last row can be all null in a DGV which will result in a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 3):

You should use :

```
intNumberOfRows = dgvWellsFargo.RowCount - 1;
```

The reason is, if you have 5 rows in your gridview, then the count will be 5 and if you know, row index starts with 0. So `dgvWellsFargo.Rows[intNumberOfRows]` means `dgvWellsFargo.Rows[5]`, but you have max row index 4

Also, you have 2 cells, so the cell index should be used `Cells[0] and Cells[1]`

So your final code should be :

```
int lastRowIndex = dgvWellsFargo.RowCount - 1;

txtNoOfTransactions.Text = dgvWellsFargo.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
txtTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c2}", dgvWellsFargo.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Cells[1] and Cells[2] also must be Cells[0] and Cells[1]

Comment: that's true as he has 2 cells

Comment: I'd rename the variable given that it doesn't represent the number of rows, rather the index of the last row

Comment: @HasaniH I agree

Comment: I tried that and I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " even though when I look at the variable it has the number of rows - 1.  The source of the datagrid is CSV file and when I open it in Excel there are 450 rows with the first row being headers and the variable shows 449.

Comment: @Donald I am not getting clear, what's the value of `lastRowIndex ` when you get the error?

Comment: The value of the variable is 449.

Comment: The value should be 448. I guess your last row in the grid is an empty row, so you can try with `int lastRowIndex = dgvWellsFargo.RowCount - 2;`